# Not able to connect to github repo via ssh using http proxy tunnel

Tags: github, ssh, http-proxy

I am behind a proxy in my college and things like ftp and ssh don't really work out of the box. I just set up git on my laptop and I configured it's proxy and I am able to push and fetch via http(s) methods.

However I want to be able to connect via ssh to my github repo. I spent a couple of hours reading workarounds online and trying to ssh into my github repo using corkscrew to tunnel the http proxy.

My `~/.ssh/config` file looks something like this:

```
Host github.com
Hostname ssh.github.com
Port 443
ProxyCommand corkscrew proxy62.iitd.ernet.in 80 %h %p ~/.corkscrew-auth
```

Debugging the ssh attempt yields the following messages:

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/vivek/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/vivek/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec corkscrew proxy62.iitd.ernet.in 80 ssh.github.com 443 ~/.corkscrew-auth
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1000
debug1: identity file /home/vivek/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/vivek/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vivek/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vivek/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vivek/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vivek/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
Proxy could not open connnection to ssh.github.com:  Method Not Allowed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Since the proxy server here requires authentication, I created a `corkscrew.auth` file in my home directory where I put in my credentials in the form `username:password`.

How do I correctly set up ssh here? I think I should be able to ssh using http-proxy tunneling no matter what. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace **proxy62.iitd.ernet.in 80** with **10.10.78.62 3128**. In addition, you could remove the **~/.corkscew-auth** and simply stay logged into the proxy from the browser