# Connecting to github with SSH via http proxy throws 107 Service Unavailable error

Tags: windows, github, ssh, proxy

I'm having an absolute nightmare of a time getting a working ssh connection to github. I know I've gotten it working in the past, but can't for the life of me remember how.

Debug output:

```
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.113] port 22.
debug1: socket:660, io:0000025981539ED0, fd:3
debug3: w32_fcntl fd:3
debug3: w32_connect fd:3
debug3: connect - io:0000025981539ED0
debug3: connectex - io:0000025981539ED0
debug3: wait() on 1 events and 0 children
debug3: finish_connect, io:0000025981539ED0
debug1: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 107, io:0000025981539ED0
debug1: connect to address 192.30.253.113 port 22: Unknown error
debug3: w32_close fd:3
debug1: close - io:0000025981539ED0, type:1, fd:3, table_index:3
debug2: close - io:0000025981539ED0
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: No error
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

and https://www.eldos.com/documentation/sbb/documentation/ref_err_ssherrorcodes.html says that an SSH error code of `107` corresponds to the `ERROR_SSH_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` error. Doesn't really tell me much.

I've attempted to try explicitly tunnelling through my proxy, but that has had no luck. Utilising my ssh config, I've got it set to the following:

```
Host github.com
    User         git
    BatchMode    yes
    LogLevel     DEBUG3
    ProxyCommand ncat --proxy $http_proxy --proxy-type http %h %p
```

That just ends up spitting-out another error:

```
proxy connect is not supported in Windows
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'd really appreciate it if anyone can at least give me some more avenues of investigation, if not an actual solution.

The closest issue I've been able to find is [Not able to connect to github repo via ssh using http proxy tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19069486/41223), but that requires corkscrew, and getting that compiled on my windows machine is reasonably difficult (though I'm still trying).

**Edit:** The standard help documentation for github isn't much use in this case, since the error I'm getting isn't related to key authentication. Running the suggested `ssh -T git@github.com` results in pretty much the same error:

```
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.112] port 22.
debug1: socket:612, io:000001AB50DC8A90, fd:3
debug3: w32_fcntl fd:3
debug3: w32_connect fd:3
debug3: connect - io:000001AB50DC8A90
debug3: connectex - io:000001AB50DC8A90
debug3: wait() on 1 events and 0 children
debug3: finish_connect, io:000001AB50DC8A90
debug1: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 107, io:000001AB50DC8A90
debug1: connect to address 192.30.253.112 port 22: Unknown error
debug3: w32_close fd:3
debug1: close - io:000001AB50DC8A90, type:1, fd:3, table_index:3
debug2: close - io:000001AB50DC8A90
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: No error
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Following https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/#platform-windows?

Comment: Error 107 may be ["Transport endpoint is not connected"](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html).

Comment: @iltempo: Nothing fancy, I'm just trying to connect to my github repos via ssh.

Comment: @Kenster: It's a possiblilty, but what would that mean in this context?